# Links not working fully on Android

Tags: css, mobile, href

At http://sallymilo.com/rupe/contact.html, the 3 navigation links work as expected on a monitor, but when I make the browser narrow or view the page on my Android, the links either don't work at all or each can be clicked only once, then no more in the same session. Any solution?

Comment: You should post an [MCVE] on this question, not refer to an external website.

Comment: @sally please check my code its work

Answer (score 0):

The `p` tag you are using for milodesign.com is covering the other elements at those sizes. You should put it inside it's own div, but really if you add `clear: both` to that p tag's style, it will fix it.

Comment: Thank you all...Just removing the position tag alone didn't fix it, but the combo of all 3 worked. (Though I think the p tag thing didn't contribute to the issue...) THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Below section of your code is causing issue, in smaller devices below

tag is taking 100% height and covering whole screen thus disabling all links :

```
<p align="center" style="text-align:right;" class="alinks"> 
<a href="http://www.milodesign.com">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">
    Design by Sally Milo - MiloDesign
</font>
</a>
</p>
```

When I removed **position:relative** from alinks class in CSS, all those links were working in mobile screens.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Changes this CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .alinks {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 90%;
            margin-top: -2em;
            margin-bottom: -2em;
            overflow:hidden;
    }
}
```